# How to find out who created a Azure Service Bus queue?

Tags: azure

Is there any way to determine who created a Service Bus queue and forwarded the messages from an existing Service Bus Queue to it?

We tried the steps in the blog [Determine Who Created Resources in Azure](http://blog.itaysk.com/2017/06/25/determine-who-created-resources-in-azure), but that does not work if the Service Bus Queue is created using Service Bus Explorer (we've tested that).   We had an incident where a new Service Bus Queue was created with the name of an existing one, with temp added to the end, which caused some issues, so we are trying to determine what or who caused it.